# Reversing order of a list using only the len() function

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
def reverse_list(list1):
    length = len(list1)
    for i in range(length):
        list1[i] = list1[(length - 1) - i]
    return list1
```

I have here a function that in theory should reverse the order of any give 1D list. It changes the list in place I believe, so the original list is modified. That is okay. The list i am using is 
`list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

The theory:

```
list[0] = list[4-0] = list[4] # 5
list[1] = list[4-1] = list[3] # 4
list[2] = list[4-2] = list[2] # 3
list[3] = list[4-3] = list[1] # 2
list[4] = list[4-4] = list[0] # 1
```

which should give me `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` but instead gives back `[5, 4, 3, 4, 5]`. I cannot figure out why this is. I am only using the `len()` function, no other built-in function for lists.

Comment: What makes you think list[0] is 1 on the last line, when the first one shows you changing it to 5? (The `list[4] =` line won't actually happen at all, because `range()` stops before the argument, not at it, but this is the problem with the next to last line, anyway...)

Comment: `range` is also a function... are you sure that's allowed :)

Comment: Right, I see the problem. I made the range function go all the way, but the problem is that the last two numbers have already been assigned to `list[0]` and `list[1]` which is why they are there. I'll have to make a new list, instead of changing it in place.

Comment: (adding `print(list1)` before and after the assignment in the `for` loop should give you a great view of what's happening, and probably will enlighten you as to why your algorithm can never work).

Comment: Also, are you aware of the `reversed()` builtin and the `.reverse()` method on lists? :)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of those builtins, but I don't want to use them. I'm trying to figure out how to write my own function to do that. It seems this algorithm is great for making mirrored lists in place, but not reversed lists. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Note that in python `list1[(length - 1) - i]` is the same as `list1[-1 - i]`

Comment: Without any other context, you are loosing some information at the line `list1[i] = list1[(length - 1) - i]`. To make it more apparent, let the length is 10, and i is zero. Then the assignment says `list1[0] = list1[9]`. Then you are loosing the element `list1[0]`. No chance to get it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using any functions at all:

```
rev_list = original[::-1]
```

Or if for some reason using `len` is a requirement:

```
rev_list = original[::-len('1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because you're reading form the list you just changed! So you set list[0] to 5 then later set list[4] to list[0] which you've just changed to 5 :)

```
                              # contained    set to
list[0] = list[4-0] = list[4] # 1            list[4] which is 5
list[1] = list[4-1] = list[3] # 2            list[3] which is 4
list[2] = list[4-2] = list[2] # 3            list[2] which is 3
list[3] = list[4-3] = list[1] # 4            list[1] which is now 4
list[4] = list[4-4] = list[0] # 5            list[4] which is now 5
```

I really like Eric's way though :D